# Trying to create a loop to add variables from an array to another array

Tags: python, loops, variables

This is 100% a super noob question (i just started on python).
I'm trying to print all on my variable values that I have put in an array called "variables" and I want to add that to the array of strings called "names"
Basically I am trying to print all of the variables with x = "it's number", t  = "it's number", etc, and i'm trying to do it in a vertical column.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
x = np.array([1,3,4])
t = np.array([4,6,10])
X = sum(x)                   # X = 8
T = sum(t)                   # T = 20
S = sum(x **2)               # S = 26
P = sum(x*t)                 # P = 62
D = ((3*S) - (X **2))        # D = 14
m = ((3*P) - (X*T))/(D)      # m = 1.86
c = ((T*S) - (X*P))/(D)      # c = 1.71
e0 = t[0] - (m * x[0]) - c   # e0 = 0.429
e1 = t[1] - (m * x[1]) - c   # e1 = -1.29
e2 = t[2] - (m * x[2]) - c   # e2 = 0.857
E = (e0 ** 2) + (e1 ** 2) + (e2 ** 2)       # e= 2.57
dm = math.sqrt((3 * E)/ ((3 * S) - (X ** 2)))   # dm = 0.742
dc = math.sqrt((S * E)/((3 * S) - (X ** 2)))    # dc = 2.19
names = ['x = ',  't =',  'X =', 'T =', 'S =', 'P =', 'D =', 'm =', 'c =', 'e0 =', 'e1 =', 'e2 =', 'E =']
variables = [x, t, X, T, S, P, D, m, c, e0, e1, e2, E, dm, dc]
print(names[0], variables[0])*
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
for i in range(how many loops):
```

This is how to do loops in python

Answer (score 0):

Matching up lists item for item is a job for [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip).

Here you can do something like:

```
names = ['x = ',  't =',  'X =', 'T =', 'S =', 'P =', 'D =', 'm =', 'c =', 'e0 =', 'e1 =', 'e2 =', 'E =']
variables = [x, t, X, T, S, P, D, m, c, e0, e1, e2, E, dm, dc]

for name, value in zip(names, variables):
    print(f'{name} {value}')
```

Which will give you:

```
x =  [1 3 4]
t = [ 4  6 10]
X = 8
T = 20
S = 26
P = 62
D = 14
m = 1.8571428571428572
c = 1.7142857142857142
e0 = 0.4285714285714286
e1 = -1.2857142857142854
e2 = 0.857142857142857
E = 2.5714285714285703
```

You can also create a dictionary the same way, which might be an easier way to manage all these values:

```
dict(zip(names, variables))

{'x': array([1, 3, 4]),
 't': array([ 4,  6, 10]),
 'X': 8,
 'T': 20,
 'S': 26,
 'P': 62,
 'D': 14,
 'm': 1.8571428571428572,
 'c': 1.7142857142857142,
 'e0': 0.4285714285714286,
 'e1': -1.2857142857142854,
 'e2': 0.857142857142857,
 'E': 2.5714285714285703}
```

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense.
Thank you so much for your help!